# Система личных сообщений

Tags: php

Учусь делать самую простую систему сообщений, между двумя пользователями, где на сообщение можно ответить только 1 раз и это сообщение и ответ, видны у обоих пользователей.

Вот в чём вопрос: если 1 пользователь хочет удалить какое-нибудь сообщение из своего списка всех сообщений и если он его удалит, то оно пропадёт из БД и тогда у другого пользователя оно из списка тоже исчезнет.

Может в таком случае, сначала записать в бд, в какую-нибудь строку этого сообщения, то что 1 пользователь уже не хочет его отображать и записать цифру 1 и потом проверять, если эта цифра есть, то этому пользователю такое сообщение не выводить и когда уже второй пользователь захочет его удалить, то ещё в одну строку записывается цифра 1 и потом уже сравнивается, если цифра 1 есть в обеих строках, то удалить его из базы?

Comment: Нет, удалять вообще ничего не нужно

Comment: ну можно не в отдельную строку, а просто поле в сообщении под это завести. в нем например ID пользователя, который удалил у себя это сообщение. Пока сообщение есть у обоих, то в этом поле NULL, когда кто то удаляет, его ID пишется в поле. Если сообщение удаляют и в поле уже есть ID - то его можно удалять вообще из БД. Только при такой схеме если вы вдруг в будущем захотите сделать нормальные многопользовательские чаты все придется переделывать с нуля и проектировать совсем по другому

Comment: @DivMan можно к примеру добавить в таблицу для хранения сообщений колонку visible со значением по умолчанию 1, и построить sql-запросы так, чтобы выборка сообщений происходила по условию WHERE visible = 1 Если кто-то удалил сообщение, то в поле visible записывать 0, и это сообщение в выборку не попадёт ни у одного, ни у другого юзера, но в базе оно по прежнему будет храниться для вас.

Answer (score 5):

Когда-нибудь вы захотите дать поговорить более чем двоим пользователям, поэтому колонки плодить не получится.

Можно реализовать, например, вот так:

```
  User(id, ...)  
  Thread(id, title, ...) // разговор  
  UserThread(user_id, thread_id) // участники разговора   
  Message(id, author_id, thread_id, text, ...) // сообщения  
  UserMessage(user_id, message_id) // что видит пользователь
```

Удаляете только связку пользователя с сообщением, оригинальные сообщения оставляете даже если его больше никто не видит, пригодятся.